# Proper syntax to use std::map access operator [] via std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr, stdmap

My question is really simple. I googled a lot, but somehow I cannot figure it out. I use a C++ `std::map` with a `std::unique_pointer` like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::map<int,std::string>> my_map( new std::map<int,std::string>());
```

Now, I want to use the access operator `[]` of the map. But I always get a compiler error.

```
my_map[1] = "XYZ";    // error C2676
my_map->[1] = "XYZ";  // error C2059
```

Without the `std::unique_ptr`, my code would be like below, and it works. But how do I do the same via `std::unique_ptr`? Please help me.

```
std::map<int,std::string> my_map;
my_map[1] = "XYZ";   // OK!
```

Modern C++ is welcome and even desired.

Comment: Note that there is also the `at()` method, which might be more "elegant" to use with a pointer, `my_map->at(1)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Call operator function manually

```
my_map->operator[](1)
```

or dereference pointer and call `operator []`

```
(*my_map)[1]
```

Comment: Great, both ways worked for me! Exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

I find `(*my_map)[1]` to be annoying.  The problem is order of operations.

We can use a named operator to invert the order of operations as follows:

```
namespace easy_op {
  enum class supported_ops {
    index,
    invoke,
  };
  template<class Rhs, supported_ops>
  struct op_t {
    Rhs rhs;
  };
  constexpr static struct do_opt {
    template<class Rhs>
    constexpr op_t<Rhs, supported_ops::index>
    operator[](Rhs&& rhs)const{
      return {std::forward<Rhs>(rhs)};
    }
    template<class Rhs>
    constexpr op_t<Rhs, supported_ops::invoke>
    operator()(Rhs&& rhs)const{
      return {std::forward<Rhs>(rhs)};
    }
    constexpr do_opt() {}
  } const op;
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  constexpr auto operator*( Lhs&& lhs, op_t<Rhs, supported_ops::index>&& rhs )
  -> decltype( (*std::declval<Lhs>())[std::declval<Rhs>()] )
  {
    return (*std::forward<Lhs>(lhs))[std::forward<Rhs>(rhs.rhs)];
  }
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  constexpr auto operator*( Lhs&& lhs, op_t<Rhs, supported_ops::invoke>&& rhs )
  -> decltype( (*std::declval<Lhs>())(std::declval<Rhs>()) )
  {
    return (*std::forward<Lhs>(lhs))(std::forward<Rhs>(rhs.rhs));
  }
}
using easy_op::op;
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3db0f196fd3cb4c0).

```
std::unique_ptr< std::vector<int> > p = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>();
*p = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < p->size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << p*op[i];
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: `(*p)[i]` may be annoying, but its meaning is instantly clear, in stark contrast to `p*op[i]` (which, btw, is at least equally annoying)

Comment: @Walter Good point.  Maybe I should overload `p->*[i]` instead.  ;)